# Как определить момент завершения построения только что вставленного Html-кода?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Добрый день.
Допустим, есть некая простая HTML-страничка.
Нам надо при помощи JavaScript динамически изменить содержание одного div-контейнера и сразу задать некие события и свойства компонентам, только что вставленным в этот DIV-контейнер. Вроде все просто: взять ссылку на нужный html-компонент и потом задать все необходимые свойства вновь вставленным. Но тут возникла проблема.
Сразу после вставки html-кода в div-контейнер, команда <code>getElementById</code> либо подобные команды этого семейства, не всегда находят только что добавленный элемент. Т.е. эта команда отрабатывается, вроде как, в то время, когда элемента еще не существует. Ну так вот и вопрос, который назрел у меня глядя на эту ситуацию:   
*Как можно после добавления html-кода внутрь контейнера, определить когда он построился и его можно использовать?*

**UPD1:**

```
//... Произошла инициализация контейнеров
var containers = me.getReadyFormsContainers();
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    var c = containers[i];
    //Добавляем в текущую панель построенную форму
    this.add(c);
}

//... ...
// Задаем слушатель контейнеру (для  "var containers")
wrapper.addListener("painted", this.applyProps, this);
//....
// наша функция, в которой получается исключительная ситуация
applyProps: function() {
    var me = this,
          element = Ext.get(me.getComponentId());
    /* На компьютере, в 90% случаях все строится хорошо, в 10% - элемент не находится
        На телефонах, в 70% случаях один из компонентов не находится. */
}
```

Все сделано на Sencha Touch 2. Могу вкратце рассказать алгоритм действий сенчавского элемента: 
<code>this.add(c);</code> - в с находится готовый к вставке компонент. При команде <code>add</code>, компонент отрисовывается в панели. Сразу после команды вставки Html, происходит событие <code>painted</code> и вызывается функция <code>applyProps</code>.

Comment: А код можно увидеть? Насколько я знаю - изменение innerHTML элемента на 100% синхронно.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще `getElementById` понадобился, если вы итак имеете ссылку на вставляемый контейнер?

Comment: Внутри контейнера мы ставим еще несколько контейнеров, к которым надо привязать действия.

Comment: @Антон Мухин ID уникальные( мало ли )?

Вообще, скорее всего, у вас какая-то баянистая проблема в логике. Хотя, возможно, метод add асинхронный (вряд-ли, но мало-ли), тогда действительно - нужно переписывать код

Comment: А что потом с `element` происходит? Почему это нельзя сделать при создании/добавлении контейнера? 

    var c = containers[i];
    this.applyProp(c);
    this.add(c);

Зачем сначала добавлять элемент в DOM, а затем сразу же его искать нем?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - это не имеет никакого значения, работать будет так и так

Comment: Да, ID уникальные. Проверил хорошо.  
Но все-таки вы утверждаете что сто процентов - изменение внутреннего html - сразу задает в DOM новые элементы? Плюс еще тут же такое что на компьютере почти всегда строится все верно.

Comment: Вот пример я выложил на каком-то бесплатном хостинге:  
http://m.amoukhine.16mb.com/  
проверять только в гугл-хроме или сафари. Проблемный файл со скриптом: Component.
MCPays.view.core.Component. Строка 202. Там некоторые компоненты не могут быть найдены.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я не утверждал обратного. Вопрос касался лишь не оптимальной логики.

Answer (score 2):

Я извиняюсь, но это работающее решение на **jQuery**, требующее подключения библиотеки,
Из-за того, что объект динамически создан, нужно цеплять события к этому объекту спец. методом **.delegate()**

```
<div id="obj">
<span>Я рожден динамически</span>
</div>

jQuery("#obj").delegate("span","click",function(){ //цепляем click на span
    //здесь тело функции
})
```

Так же можно использовать **.live()**